# Postage calculator not outputting in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm having a bit of trouble with a postage calculator I've created via Javascript, it should take a quantity and create a variable which is that multiplied by a defined number (i.e. postage cost) and then output the total (sum of all variables). It's working perfectly in all browsers except IE, which leads me to believe that the issue lies not with the JavaScript, but perhaps the HTML. I thought I'd narrowed the issue down to the `<output>` tag, but I've tried swapping this out with a `<span>` and yet the problem persists:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
        var let1 = document.getElementById('let1').value;   
        var let1f = let1 * 0.12;        
        var let2 = document.getElementById('let2').value;   
        var let2f = let2 * 0.16;        
        var ll1 = document.getElementById('ll1').value; 
        var ll1f = ll1 * 0.17;      
        var ll2 = document.getElementById('ll2').value; 
        var ll2f = ll2 * 0.12;      
        var sp01 = document.getElementById('sp01').value;   
        var sp01f = sp01 * 0.30;        
        var sp02 = document.getElementById('sp02').value;   
        var sp02f = sp02 * 0.30;        
        var sp11 = document.getElementById('sp11').value;   
        var sp11f = sp11 * 0.30;        
        var sp12 = document.getElementById('sp12').value;   
        var sp12f = sp12 * 0.30;        
        var mp01 = document.getElementById('mp01').value;   
        var mp01f = mp01 * 0.85;
        var mp02 = document.getElementById('mp02').value;   
        var mp02f = mp02 * 0.80;
        var mp11 = document.getElementById('mp11').value;   
        var mp11f = mp11 * 1.4;
        var mp12 = document.getElementById('mp12').value;   
        var mp12f = mp12 * 1.15;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        result.value = parseFloat(let1f + let2f + ll1f + ll2f + sp01f +sp02f + sp11f +sp12f +mp01f + mp02f + mp11f + mp12f).toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator">
        <ul class="column" id="column1">
            <li class="topbar" id="format">Format</li>
            <li>Letters</li>
            <li>Large Letters</li>
            <li>Small Parcel (0-1kg)</li>
            <li>Small Parcel (1-2kg)</li>
            <li>Medium Parcel (0-1kg)</li>
            <li>Medium Parcel (1-2kg)</li>
            <li class="saving">Weekly Saving</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="column" id="column2">
            <li class="topbar">First Class</li>
            <li><input id="let1" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="ll1" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="sp01" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="sp11" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="mp01" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="mp11" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li class="saving">=</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="column" id="column2">
            <li class="topbar">Second Class</li>
            <li><input id="let2" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="ll2" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="sp02" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="sp12" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="mp02" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li><input id="mp12" type="number" oninput="calculate()"/></li>
            <li class="result">&pound;<output id="result"/></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited to follow the guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `output` tag is not supported by Internet Explorer (and Safari)
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp

You can just use a `span` in it's place. And instead of setting `result.value` use `result.innerHTML`